# What controls the presence of the twisties in pyqt QTreeView?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I have a minimal working PyQt (6, Win) tree view (`QTreeView`) and model (`QAbstractItemModel`), and while the tree is displayed with correct indentation, it is missing the triangular twisties to allow tree nodes to be expanded and compressed. What am I missing? Does it need to be marked editable or some event enabled or suchlike? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mre].